# Creeper Lighting

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

There are two sets of similar but separate puzzles here; the white puzzle (with white cells) and the black puzzle (with black cells). Each puzzle is solved independently.

Each number is a "lightsaber". It may influence $n+1$ consecutive cells in any direction, horizontal, vertical, or diagonal, starting from itself. For instance, a $0$ lights up itself, a $1$ lights up itself and a neighbor, and a $7$ lits up its row, column, or diagonal, since this is an $8\times8$ grid. Solve each puzzle such that cells of the same color, and only the same color, is lighted. Lightsabers may not swipe outside of the puzzle's boundary.

[image]

Example:

[image]

Comment: The description says that 7 lights up its row or column, but the example has a 1 with a diagonal. Are diagonals allowed for 7's?

Comment: Yes, sorry. IHATE15CHAR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

There's arguably a mistake in the puzzle, as

> The direction of the bottom-right black 1 can point either north or northwest. The easiest way to fix seems to be to change the top left black 4 to a 3 instead.

Comment: My mistake, also yah I intended to make the top left black 4 a 3. Sorry.